# Mysql Filter two dates between two columns

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get result which will be filter two dates between two dates. To give more background - I have a table with employee holidays and I want to get all dates when employees are on holiday in selected date range.

**Example:**

Employee 1 have holidays in date range from 2022-07-20 to 2022-07-30

Employee 2 have holidays in date range from 2022-07-22 to 2022-07-25

Table looks like:

```
ID    employee_id  StartDate      EndDate
 1      1          2022-07-20    2022-07-30
 2      2          2022-07-22    2022-07-25
```

And what I want to do is filter all employees who have holidays in date range 2022-07-21 - 2022-07-28

When I'm trying something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM emp_holidays WHERE StartDate >= '2022-07-21' and EndDate <= '2022-07-28'
```

Then I'm getting only second record from database, because only one employee is matching this filter, but I know on this date rande first employee is also on holidays.

**What will be the best result?**

```
eployee_id date
1          2022-07-21
1          2022-07-22
1          2022-07-23
1          2022-07-24
1          2022-07-25
1          2022-07-26
1          2022-07-27
1          2022-07-28
2          2022-07-22
2          2022-07-23
2          2022-07-24
2          2022-07-25
```

Another amazing result will be

```
eployee_id date_from  date_to
1          2022-07-21 2022-07-25
2          2022-07-22 2022-07-25
```

Any help will be amazing :)

I'm thinking about new helper table with dates for next ~50 years, and then getting datas from helper tab, and then checking if `StartDate` is in select from helper table result, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution.

Comment: does using `or` unacceptable?

Comment: I was trying a lot of queries, we can use everything what we want. OR, AND, Helper Table, Procedures etc. But I don't know how it should look. I can get date from date range, but when I need to get all dates when employees are on holiday it is really hard for me.

Comment: @BagusTesa I've update already my question with last paragraph. Please let me know it is a good solution.

Comment: The ranges overlaps when each range start is less than opposite range end. So `WHERE StartDate <= '2022-07-28' and EndDate >=  '2022-07-21'`. The overlapping range is from the greatest of starts till the least of ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akina is right, I didn't think that way earlier (silly me). Expanding upon their comment, we can use [`CASE` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) to pick the matching dates for `StartDate` and `EndDate`. Given the filter is for getting employee's holiday between 21-07-2022 and 28-07-2022, we can make query like this:

```
select
  id, employee_id,
  case when StartDate >='2022-07-21'
       then StartDate
       else '2022-07-21' end
       as StartDate,
  case when EndDate <= '2022-07-28'
       then EndDate
       else '2022-07-28' end
       as EndDate
from holidays
where StartDate <= '2022-07-28' and EndDate >= '2022-07-21'
```

It will outputs the following:

| id | employee_id | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-07-21 | 2022-07-28 |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-07-22 | 2022-07-25 |
| 3 | 3 | 2022-07-21 | 2022-07-23 |
| 4 | 4 | 2022-07-22 | 2022-07-28 |

See more on Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oDs1SkhdeRP2jznyrzVArk/0

Though, I'm not quite sure why on your second example (with the constrained `StartDate` and `EndDate`) it shows 25 instead of 28 for the one with `EndDate` at 30.